# No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at:

Tags: android

I got this problem when I try to add a dependencie in app build.gradle.

The module which I want to add is complecated.

First, I create a gradle plugin project called 'injector'.

```
class ModulePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        System.out.println("========== this is a log just from PluginDemo ==========")
        // I create a injector extension . But I don't think it leading to this error.
        InjectConfig config = project.extensions.create("injector", InjectConfig.class)
        def android = project.extensions.getByType(LibraryExtension)
        initExtension(project, config)
        ModuleTransform transform = new ModuleTransform(config)
        android.registerTransform(transform)
    }
    
    ... //Nothing improtant
}
```

Second, I create another android module called 'mediaTool'. This module's root project build.gradle add 'injector' for it's classpath.

```
 dependencies {
    classpath "cn.xdf.demo:injector:0.0.10"
    ... // Nothing important 
 }
```

The 'mediaTool' module run perfectly.

In the END, I bring 'mediaTool' into my main project :

```
dependencies{
    implementation rootProject.ext.dependencies["mediaTool"]
    ... //Nothing important
}
```

I could not pass the Gralde Sync and I got this issue.

```
No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at:
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidModule.prepare(GradleModules.kt:266)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker.populateAndroidModels(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:99)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:92)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderImpl.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:112)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProvider.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:50)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:400)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:138)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
```

What I did wrong???